# TypeError: arr.reduce is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, reduce

I get this error msg from time to time when I refresh the App Im building a react puzzle and I can't find what I'm missing or written wrong? Can anyone help me what I should write different?

The error msg:
`TypeError: arr.reduce is not a function flattenArray`

`const flattenArray = arr => {
  return arr.reduce((flatArr, subArr) => flatArr.concat(subArr), []);
};`

The code:

```
const getShuffledPuzzle = () => {
  const values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

  const rowOne = [],
    rowTwo = [],
    rowThree = [];

  while (values.length) {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)

    if (rowOne.length < 3) {
      rowOne.push(values.splice(random, 1)[0])
    } else if (rowTwo.length < 3) {
      rowTwo.push(values.splice(random, 1)[0])
    } else {
      rowThree.push(values.splice(random, 1)[0])
    }
  }
  return [rowOne, rowTwo, rowThree]
}
```

This is where I get the TypeError:

`````
const flattenArray = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((flatArr, subArr) => flatArr.concat(subArr), [])
};

const getInversionCount = arr => {
  arr = flattenArray(arr).filter(n => n !== 0)
  const inversions = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    const currentValue = arr[i]
    const currentInversions = arr.filter(
      (val, j) => i < j && val < currentValue
    )
    inversions.push(currentInversions.length)
  }

  const inversionsCount = inversions.reduce((total, val) => total + val, 0)

  return inversionsCount
}

const isSolvable = puzzle => {
  return getInversionCount(puzzle) % 2 === 0
};

const getPuzzle = () => {
  let puzzle = getShuffledPuzzle()

  while (!isSolvable(puzzle)) {
    puzzle = getShuffledPuzzle
  }
  return puzzle
}


````
`````

Comment: This code looks okay. The parameter (arr) you are passing might not be array, hence the error. Can you please post the entire code here?

Comment: sounds like you are not passing in an array.  `.... arr => { console.log(Array.isArray(arr), arr); `

Comment: Have you tried ``_.flattenDeep(arr)`` from lodash?

Comment: I put most of the code in here now,  thanks for looking! @ShubhawKumar

Comment: I posted more code here now, thanks for looiking! @epascarello

Comment: I've never tried _.flattenDeep(arr) from lodash, so i will look in to that, thank @TomásDenisReyesSánchez

Comment: `puzzle = getShuffledPuzzle` <---

Comment: @TomásDenisReyesSánchez there is also [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) nowadays.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello 

Answer (score 0):

For safe flatten, use default value as array.

```
const flattenArray = (arr = []) => arr.reduce((flatArr, subArr) => flatArr.concat(subArr), [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this error and narrowed it down to this code:

```
const [availableNums, setAvailableNums] = useState([1,2,3,4,5]);
const [candidateNums, setcandidateNums] = useState(6,7);
```

I needed to pass in an array **[6, 7]** *not two arguments: 6, 7*:

```
const [candidateNums, setcandidateNums] = useState([6,7]);
```